# Symfony on Nitrous.IO, missing the INTL pecl extension

Tags: php, symfony, nitrousio, intl

I am trying to set up my Symfony application on the Nitrous platform. It is recommended to have translations with help of the INTL pecl module, so I tried to install it (pecl install intl). But it seems that it's missing lib ICU headers. These are installed by default when you install php5-intl (through apt-get) but I does not have the right permissions. How can this issue be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation chapter [The Intl Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html).

composer should automatically install `symfony/intl: 1.0.*` if the intl extension isn't available. Please note that you're limited to the `en` locale this way.

Check your `phpinfo()` output if the `php-intl` extension is available/enabled and if yes which ICU version it was compiled with.

If the extension isn't available/enabled and you have no way to install it ... you will need to use the fallback-version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The fallback is indeed sufficient.